# WPF Desinger window does not render the view in Visual studio 2012

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.5

I am using Visual studio 2012 and working with WPF, whenever i create a new widow, then it's designer window is not shown. However,when we run the application,dialog is displayed.
But my question is this why i can't see the designer of WPF dialog while i am writing xaml want to see effects on designer.

Is this an issue with Visual studio 2012 because this happening on all the developer machines in my company.

Is there any patch setup for visual studio other than upate1 and update2 that i have already installed for my visual studio but nothing has been fixed up by now.

Comment: Do you think this is a software issue with VS2012? Does your datacontext have a default constructor?

Comment: Yes there is an update 3 plus I believe there is an update 4 that is close to being released. Does it fail on a new project or only an existing one?